# Rotativa 1.7.4 ActionAsPDF, Remove Navbar and Print button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am trying to remove the navbar and print button from the page that I am trying to print. I attempted to use CustomSwitches but Rotativa does not appear to like them.

```
string customSwitches = 
    "--disable-smart-shrinking --header-html {0} --footer-html {1}";

var printForm = new ActionAsPdf("Receipt", new { id = id })
{
    PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.Legal,
    CustomSwitches = customSwitches
};

return printForm;
```

My view for reference: [Print view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOHMg.png).

What are some thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `--print-media-type` custom switch.
2. Apply the class `no-print` for your navbar div and button

Then write your CSS like this

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```